# How to create this gw basic program?

Tags: basic, gw-basic

Ok i want to know how to make a sentence appear word by word in GW BASIC.For example if the sentence is I Am Boy then how to make it appear as so "I" comes first printed then "A" ,then "m" , then B and so on....simply like in typing 
Plz help me And it will be appreciated if you post a working programme codingg

Comment: Please write 1,000 times "I will do my own homework". Do not use a loop or recursive function.

Comment: LOL this is not a homework.I was creating a game but i don't know how to make words of sentence appear one by one rather then appering as a whole.

Comment: Use a While...Wend loop and the Timer function to wait for your desired amount of time to pass before printing out the next letter.

Comment: hi idle can you tell me how to use timer in while wend loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that waits three seonds:

```
T! = TIMER + 3: WHILE TIMER < T!: WEND
```

Answer (score 1):

```
10 cls
20 rem variables go here
30 print A$
40 gosub 500 REM Timer Here
50 print B$
60 gosub 500
```

etc

```
510 Otime=val(right$(time$,2))
520 Ntime=val(right$(time$,2))
530 if Ntime-Otime>3 or Ntime-Otime<0 then return else goto 510
```

This should work, if not, it will lie in the 500 lines and should only need a minor adjustment.